# python datetime timestamp bug before 1968

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I found that some bug on calculation timestamp in datetime module.

The second of a day is not 86400.

Is it a bug? or is there any other reason?

```
for n in range(2,2015):
    ts1=datetime.fromisoformat(str(n).zfill(4)+'-01-01T00').timestamp()
    ts2=datetime.fromisoformat(str(n+1).zfill(4)+'-01-01T00').timestamp()
    days=(ts2-ts1)/24./3600.

    if (days == 365) or (days == 366):
        jul=365
        if np.mod(n,4) == 0:
            jul=366
        if np.mod(n,100) == 0:
            jul=365
        if np.mod(n,400) == 0:
            jul=366
        if days != jul:
            print(str(n).zfill(4)+'-01-01T00',days) #-> nothing OK
    else:
        #print(str(n).zfill(4)+'-01-01T00',days)
        for d in range(-10,370):
            ts=ts1+d*24.*3600.
            iso1=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).isoformat()
            iso2=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts+24.*3600.).isoformat()
            if (iso1[11:] != iso2[11:]):
                print(iso1,iso2,
                      datetime.fromisoformat(iso2).timestamp()-datetime.fromisoformat(iso1).timestamp())

--------
1889-12-31T00:00:00 1890-01-01T00:02:08 86400.0
1904-11-30T00:00:00 1904-12-01T00:30:00 86400.0
1927-12-31T00:00:00 1927-12-31T23:30:00 84600.0
1931-12-31T00:00:00 1932-01-01T00:30:00 86400.0
1954-03-20T00:00:00 1954-03-20T23:00:00 82800.0
1961-08-09T00:00:00 1961-08-10T00:30:00 86400.0
1968-09-30T00:00:00 1968-10-01T00:30:00 86400.0
```

Comment: what is your local time zone?

Comment: I think your `timestamp()` is the problem. Note: the dates you shows seems ok on standard changes of times (moving local time to a timezone in 1927), and it is a daylight change on last (23h). So the timestamp requires a non naive time (so a time with timezone), and that creates problems, because times changed

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. You're using naive datetime objects (you don't set a time zone), which means that Python will assume they represent local time by default. However `timestamp()` returns UNIX time, which refers to UTC.

Example. My machine is set to time zone `Europe/Berlin` which had a DST change on Mar 29th, 2020.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t0, t1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-29"), datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-30")

t1.timestamp()-t0.timestamp()
# 82800.0
```

If I do the same thing but specify that my datetime objects should represent UTC, everything works as you expect:

```
t0 = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-29").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
t1 = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-30").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

t1.timestamp()-t0.timestamp()
# 86400.0
```

---

Side note: there's also Python's [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which will give you ***wall time*** difference. So here, you would get a timedelta of 1 day in both cases:

```
t1-t0
# datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: It caused by timezone. Thank you very much!

Comment: @coastocean: glad I could help! if that solved your problem, have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)